# Dart pubsec.yaml - Because LEARN_DART_BEGINNER doesn't support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I try to add dependencies but errors appear.

**My code:**

```yaml
name: LEARN_DART_BEGINNER
description: A simple command-line application.
version: 0.0.1
homepage: https://www.example.com

enviroment:
  sdk: '^3.0.0'

dependencies:
  path: ^1.8.3
  random_string: ^2.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  pedantic: ^1.9.0
```

**Error 1 (dart pub get):**

```
Resolving dependencies...
pubspec.yaml has no lower-bound SDK constraint.
You should edit pubspec.yaml to contain an SDK constraint:

environment:
  sdk: '^3.0.0'

See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-constraint
```

**Error 2 (dart pub add path):**

```
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.6.

Because LEARN_DART_BEGINNER doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
```

I can't find how to fix it. Help please.

I try to fix the error by modifying the sdk version, but it's the same.

Comment: Are you sure your `pubspec.yaml` file contains the exact content posted here in your question?